# ggplot: adding a frequency plot over a percentage plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am interested in doing a plot showing percentages by group.
something like this:

```
data(iris)
ggplot(iris,
       aes(x = Sepal.Length, group = factor(Species), fill = factor(Species))) + 
  geom_histogram(position = "fill")+theme_bw()
```

[image]

however, I would also like to plot a histogram showing the frequency distribution on top of this graph.
something like the plot below.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_histogram()+theme_bw()
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Note I know how to do a frequency plot by group: `ggplot(iris,aes(x = Sepal.Length, group = factor(Species), fill = factor(Species))) +  geom_histogram()+theme_bw()`. But this is not what I want. Rather I would like a small frequency distribution at the bottom of the percentage plot presented at the beginning.

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you want to overlay both charts in one plot or do want two separate charts stacked on top of each other? In the last case you could e.g. have a look at `patchwork`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(gridExtra)
p1 <- ggplot(iris,
             aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                 group = factor(Species), 
                 fill = factor(Species))) + 
  geom_histogram(position = "fill") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")

p2 <- ggplot(iris,aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                      group = factor(Species), 
                      fill = factor(Species))) +  
  geom_histogram() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, 
             heights = c(4, 1.5))
```

[image]

**Edit:** So you are looking for this then? Note that in this case the absolute values of the smaller histogram become meaningless since they were scaled down to be ~25% of the vertical chart range.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = iris,
                 aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                     group = factor(Species),
                     fill = factor(Species)),
                 position = "fill",
                 alpha = 1) +
  geom_histogram(data = iris,
                 aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                     y = ..ncount.. / 4),
                 alpha = 0.5,
                 fill = 'black')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, but I was trying to find a way to make the two plots overlap, maybe with some transparency in the frequency plot.